# How can I get this program to draw the bezier curve properly after being resized?

Tags: opengl, glut, bezier

this code draws bezier curves properly when the window is used on its original size (640 x 480) but renders the control points incorrectly when its resized.

on the click mouse function there is:

```
   if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
   // Store where the user clicked, note Y is backwards.
    abc[NUMPOINTS].setxy((float)x,(float)(SCREEN_HEIGHT - y));
    NUMPOINTS++;

    // Draw the red  dot.
    drawDot(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
```

I don't understand how the coordinate system is being handled.

Why using the SCREEN_HEIGHT conversion works on 640x480 but not in other window sizes? How can it be made universal?

On my own apps, I had been working without glutOrtho2d and just using a calculation for each X,Y but I have read this approach is better. I'd appreciate a detailed explanation to it.

**MODIFIED CODE:**

```
/* bezier.cpp by detour@metalshell.com
 *
 * Create a bezier curve by defining the three points
 * with your mouse.
 *
 * http://www.metalshell.com/
 *
 */

#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gl/Gl.h>
#include <gl/Glu.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

// CREEN_WIDTH = 640, SCREEN_HEIGHT=480;

int SCREEN_WIDTH=640;

int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
// Keep track of times clicked, on 3 clicks draw.
int NUMPOINTS = 0;

// Point class to keep it a little cleaner.
class Point {
public:
    float x, y;
    void setxy(float x2, float y2) { x = x2; y = y2; }
    const Point & operator=(const Point &rPoint) {
         x = rPoint.x;
         y = rPoint.y;

         return *this;
      }

};

Point abc[3];

void myInit() {
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPointSize(4.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,(float)SCREEN_WIDTH,0.0,(float)SCREEN_HEIGHT);

}

void drawDot(int x, int y) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
     glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void drawLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex2f(p1.x, p1.y);
      glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

// Calculate the next bezier point.
Point drawBezier(Point A, Point B, Point C, double t) {
    Point P;

    P.x = pow((1 - t), 2) * A.x + 2 * t * (1 -t) * B.x + pow(t, 2) * C.x;
    P.y = pow((1 - t), 2) * A.y + 2 * t * (1 -t) * B.y + pow(t, 2) * C.y;

    return P;
}

void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
  // If left button was clicked
  if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
      // Store where the user clicked, note Y is backwards.
      //abc[NUMPOINTS].setxy((float)x,(float)(y));
    abc[NUMPOINTS].setxy((float)x,(float)(SCREEN_HEIGHT - y));

    // abc[NUMPOINTS] es un arreglo de objetos Point, su contraparte en Casteljau es 


    NUMPOINTS++;

    // Draw the red  dot.
    drawDot(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
    //drawDot(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    // If 3 points are drawn do the curve.
    if(NUMPOINTS == 3) {
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        // Draw two legs of the triangle
        drawLine(abc[0], abc[1]);
        drawLine(abc[1], abc[2]);
        Point POld = abc[0];
        /* Draw each segment of the curve.  Make t increment in
                   smaller amounts for a more detailed curve. */
        for(double t = 0.0;t <= 1.0; t += 0.1) {
            Point P = drawBezier(abc[0], abc[1], abc[2], t);
            drawLine(POld, P);
            POld = P;
        }
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        NUMPOINTS = 0;
    }
  }
}

void myDisplay() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curve");

    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);

    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
 /* bezier.cpp by detour@metalshell.com
     *
     * Create a bezier curve by defining the three points
     * with your mouse.
     *
     * http://www.metalshell.com/
     *
     */

    #include <windows.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <gl/Gl.h>
    #include <gl/Glu.h>
    #include <gl/glut.h>

    int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
    // Keep track of times clicked, on 3 clicks draw.
    int NUMPOINTS = 0;

    // Point class to keep it a little cleaner.
    class Point {
    public:
    float x, y;
    void setxy(float x2, float y2) { x = x2; y = y2; }
    const Point & operator=(const Point &rPoint) {
         x = rPoint.x;
         y = rPoint.y;

         return *this;
      }

};

Point abc[3];

void myInit() {
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPointSize(4.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,640.0,0.0,480.0);

}

void drawDot(int x, int y) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
     glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void drawLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex2f(p1.x, p1.y);
      glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

// Calculate the next bezier point.
Point drawBezier(Point A, Point B, Point C, double t) {
    Point P;

    P.x = pow((1 - t), 2) * A.x + 2 * t * (1 -t) * B.x + pow(t, 2) * C.x;
    P.y = pow((1 - t), 2) * A.y + 2 * t * (1 -t) * B.y + pow(t, 2) * C.y;

    return P;
}

void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
  // If left button was clicked
  if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
      // Store where the user clicked, note Y is backwards.
    abc[NUMPOINTS].setxy((float)x,(float)(SCREEN_HEIGHT - y));
    NUMPOINTS++;

    // Draw the red  dot.
    drawDot(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);

    // If 3 points are drawn do the curve.
    if(NUMPOINTS == 3) {
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        // Draw two legs of the triangle
        drawLine(abc[0], abc[1]);
        drawLine(abc[1], abc[2]);
        Point POld = abc[0];
        /* Draw each segment of the curve.  Make t increment in
                   smaller amounts for a more detailed curve. */
        for(double t = 0.0;t <= 1.0; t += 0.1) {
            Point P = drawBezier(abc[0], abc[1], abc[2], t);
            drawLine(POld, P);
            POld = P;
        }
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        NUMPOINTS = 0;
    }
  }
}

void myDisplay() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curve");

    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);

    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change EVERYWHERE in your code that uses 640 or 480 to use SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT.

ie.

```
gluOrtho2D(0.0,640.0,0.0,480.0);
```

=>

```
gluOrtho2D( 0.0,(float)SCREEN_WIDTH,0.0,(float)SCREEN_HEIGHT );
```

&

```
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
```

=>

```
glutInitWindowSize( SCREEN_WDITH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
```

This way when you change SCREEN_WIDTH or SCREEN_HEIGHT you aren't relying on some values set elsewhere.  I suspect your issue is because you weren't modifying the gluOrtho2D call ...

Comment: Oh, I did that! I actually had changed to that long ago, but reverted the changes cause they didn't work. When the window is resized and one tries to draw points by clicking they appear where they shouldn't. I suspect the issue is with that weird SCREEN_HEIGHT - y conversion but I don't know how to do without it.

Comment: +1 The suggestion is very good. If it didn't work, that means you screwed something up. Do it properly, and your curves will display good.

Comment: @omgzor: Have you debugged the values that are coming in when you click on the screen?  Check what the values are for known locations (ie top-left should be roughly 0, 0 etc).  It will help you find the issue.  Debugging is king for finding this sort of problem :)

Comment: @VJo: Did you try it? It hasn't worked for me. I've checked over and over again and believe the substitution has been done properly.

Comment: @omgzor No, I didn't try, but the window resizing and setting the camera is not dependent on what is being rendered. That is why I think you didn't do it properly. I can only point you to some tutorials and examples.

Comment: @VJo: try the reposted code with the aforementioned modifications and tell me what you see.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code :

1. take a look what glutReshapeFunc
   does
2. the myDisplay function should render
   the image, and swap buffers (if you
   are doing double buffering)
3. all other functions should call
   glutPostRedisplay